# Which element is selected by a left or right click?

Tags: html, css

I have several folder icons that are created with the template:

```
<div id='folderTemplate' class="template openclosed_folder_icon subfolder" style="position:absolute; top:'30'; left:'100';">
       <img class="folder_icon" src="images/folder_closed.png"  alt="closed folder"  />
       <div class="folder_label" >name</div> 
       <img class='folder_redX' src='images/redX.png' alt='redX' title='Delete this gallery' />
</div>
```

The folders look like this:

[image]

If I left-click most folders, the e.target that comes into jQuery is the first `<img>` element, above, just below the opening `<div>` tag.  And if I right-click these folders with Chrome Debugging turned on, to inspect them, the element selected is this first `<img>` element.   But one of the folders gives me the outer `<div>`,  when I left click it or right-click it.  Does anyone have an idea what's going on?  What controls which element is actually selected by a left or right click?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be, the `<img />` element might have unselectable styles:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

The above code will make sure that the mouse pointer doesn't see that image at all, or any element for the reason.

Check this out here:

```css
input {padding: 25px 35px;}
div {pointer-events: none; position: relative; top: 15px; background: #fff; display: inline-block; left: -205px; z-index: 9999;}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Hello, World! Click Me?" />
<div>See through! Click on me!</div>
```

In the above snippet, if you try to click on the `<div />` you won't be able to do, and the pointer events directly go to the element behind it. Logically, the mouse doesn't see the `<div />` at all! Most of the reason is because of the CSS behind it, which you haven't provided, might answer this question! `:)`

To make it sure, I have also added `z-index: 999;` to the `<div />`. Still the `<div />` is unselectable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this but it wasn't what I thought.  The problem was that the template div for the folder to the left extends too far right and overlaps the folder on the right:

[image]

So when I thought I was clicking on the images folder I was actually clicking on the template div of  the Gallery folder, which blocked the mouse click from reaching the images folder.  The click wasn't bringing up the template div of the images folder.  It was bringing up the template div of the Gallery folder that overlayed the images folder.  Fix was to make the width of the template div just enough to hold the folder name so there won't be any more overlapping of folders.